# Django Error in Command Console AttributeError Models

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error when I try and display my fields within the command prompt. Any idea what would be causing this? I've tried to adjust "return self.stakeholder" to a field listed above (e.g. return self.employee) but it presents the same error (still referencing 'stakeholder')

models

```
class Stakeholder(models.Model):
    employee = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stakeholder_group = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    stakeholder_quadrant = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.stakeholder
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 72, in __getattr__
    return self.__storage__[self.__ident_func__()][name]
KeyError: 27232

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\console.py", line 87, in displayhook
    stream = _local.stream
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 74, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: stream

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\console.py", line 89, in displayhook
    return _displayhook(obj)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 255, in __repr__
    return '<%s %r>' % (self.__class__.__name__, data)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 518, in __repr__
    return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)
  File "C:\Users\zzzz\Python\Price Tracking\Django\mysite\polls\models.py", line 38, in __str__
AttributeError: 'Stakeholder' object has no attribute 'stakeholder'
```

Comment: Can you please show the code you're running that raises this error? Also, have you restarted your shell after changing the code? It's curious that the same error would appear.

Comment: @Clepsyd yes you are right, might be he didn't restart the shell after changing.

Answer (score 1):

The `self` has no attribute of `stakeholder`. You can return `stakeholder_group` or `stakeholder_quadrant` instead of `stakeholder`. You can try to return `self.employee`.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.employee)
```

Note: Also after changing code restart your shell or server whatever you are using.